# Sistema dinâmico de imagens e comportamento de SEO

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Fiz uma leitura sobre SEO e entendi que quanto maior o trafego de texto, você possuí mais conteúdo a ser indexado pelo Google.

Possuo uma aplicação que se baseia em imagens, é praticamente uma "múltipla-galeria" gerada não exatamente assim, mas mais ou menos da seguinte forma.

```
foreach(var foto in galeria){
    <img src="~/arquivos/@foto.imagem" />
}
```

Estava pensando, se criar uma tabela que contenha um título para a foto e declarar no `alt` ou  `title`, as minhas imagens passarão a ter um valor para indexação?

```
foreach(var foto in galeria){
    <img src="~/arquivos/@foto.imagem" title="@foto.titulo"/>
}
```

Além disso, pensei em gerar uma tabela na qual o usuário possa cadastrar `TAGs`. Exemplo:
A aplicação passará disso:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="HTML, CSS, XML, XHTML, JavaScript">
```

Para mais ou menos isso:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="@foreach(var tag in tags){@tag.nome,}">
```

Meu conteúdo será tratado como texto pelo Google apesar de estar recebendo o mesmo dinamicamente?

Comment: Com relação a usar `alt` e `title`, se você usar esses atributos, o Google indexará os textos deles. Isso realmente torna suas imagens mais fáceis de serem achadas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sempre que pensar em SEO pense em texto. Se quiser ter uma ideia mais aproximada como um motor de busca visualiza a sua página use o Lynx ( um browser que só lê texto). O Google afirma que não lê a meta="keywords", mas ao que parece o Yahoo e o Bing atribuem uma certa importância a essa meta tag. Quando aos atributos alt, são obrigatórios para a sua página pode ser validada. Então cada imagem deve ter sempre uma descrição que sirva de alternativa caso a imagem não possa ser exibida. O Google lê esse atributo e usa-o não só para entender a sua página , como também para exibir as imagens quando procura por imagens no google.

Comment: Acho que pra gestão total são 3 fatores: nome do arquivo (descritivo, higienizado e separado con hífens), meta dados EXIF do próprio arquivo e atributos `title` + `alt` no HTML.